# Loader-screen background gradient

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

How do i add a **background gradient to the react-native loader screen on iOS?** I am not familiar with XCode, so I dont know anything about it. I have read some answers here but I cannot identify where I have to put the code in XCode for the gradient prop in the designer view.

Comment: Use this [Library](https://github.com/heineiuo/react-native-animated-linear-gradient) for animated gradient loader screen. Follow the instruction as mention in description

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to your project "general" properties, and see if there's anything inputted in "Launch Screen File".

[image]

And then if there's any, search for the file in your project files. It could be in .xib or .storyboard. Open that file up and add a `UIImageView`, then add your gradient image there. That's it!